# ESP32 NodeMCU uart input matching strings problem

Tags: lua, uart, nodemcu

I created a small project on ESP32 with nodemcu firmware which communicates with a sim808 module via uart2. My problem is, that the response from uart many times is not easy for interpretation within lua and nodemcu.
Here a short example of my code:

```
uart.on(2, "data", "\r", function(data)
    print("Checking UART: "..data)
    if (string.match(data, "RING")) then
        print("Someone rings")
    elseif (string.match(data, "CLIP:")) then
        print("Phone number: "..data) -- shortened, I know that the whole line will appear
    elseif (string.match(data, 'NO CARRIER')) then
        print("Ring canceled")
    else
        print("Dont understand")
    end
end, 0)
```

In above case - RING and NO CARRIER inputs are matching correctly and the proper info is given. 
I have also many other such searchings which works. But when I look for the phone no (+CLIP:...) the code is ignorig this input, however I see it on the serial console output:

```
Checking UART: 


Dont understand
Checking UART: 
+CLIP: "+xxxxxxxxxxx",145,"",0,"",0

Checking UART: 


Dont understand
```

I see also that this specific answer has new line character after and the loop goes again with no chars, maybe that's why the code can't find it, but the build in function uart.on should check every line (\r).
The same issue when I get some bluetooth command, also can't put it to a variable.

Comment: What would be printed if `print("Checking UART: "..data)` is replaced with `print("Checking UART: "..table.concat({string.byte(data,1,-1)}, ","))`?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff:  
`Checking UART: 10,13  
Dont understand  
Checking UART: 10,82,73,78,71,13  
Dont understand  
Checking UART: 10,13  
Dont understand  
Checking UART:10,43,67,76,73,80,58,32,34,43,52,56,53,51,51,48,48,51,48,51,51,34,44,49,52,53,44,34,34,44,48,44,34,34,44,48,13  
Checking UART: 10,13  
Dont understand  
Checking UART: 10,78,79,32,67,65,82,82,73,69,82,13`

Comment: If `string.match('\n+CLIP: "+40000000000",145,"",0,"",0\r', 'CLIP:')` doesn't return the string `CLIP:` then you should send bugreport to nodemcu

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff  
If I set this command manualy in code and return to console it returns correct values. The problem is only to get it live from uart response.

Comment: Probably this depends on where string `data` is located: in RAM or in ROM.  Try to create this string in run-time, for example: `data = '\n+CLI'; data=data..'P: "+4000"...'; print(string.match(data, ...))`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff  That probably was it. I needn't even to split the data variable, only set for example new_data = data and now it's working as expected.  Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget to send the bugreport.